# Header, hr and btn at the same line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a header with a hr and a button at the same line. Something like this:

Header ------------------------------------ Button

[image: See image]
I've tried with display flex, but the hr changed for a vertical line.

```css
.flex-header {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-header">
<h2> Des habitations pour tous </h2>
<hr/>
<button> Collections </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a `<div>` with some [css](/questions/tagged/css) to create a `<hr>`-like line;

```css
.flex-header {
  display: flex;
}

.line {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 1px;
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0 20px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-header">
<h2> Des habitations pour tous </h2>
<div class="line"></div>
<button> Collections </button>
</div>
```

Comment: The solution is good, but why the button is too big now? How can I make it have a normal height?

Comment: The button is the same size as the original question. Howevery, something like `button { height: 25px; }` should shrink the button?

Comment: great!
https://codepen.io/analuspi/pen/vYydeKE

Answer (score 0):

you need change te display property of h2 element, by default it is "block", change to "in-line" (so the button is show in side of header)

```css
h2{
  diplay: inline;
}
```

To horizontal line, remove the display flex and change hr property:

```css
h2{
  hr{ 
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
}
```

Look project:
https://codepen.io/Luis4raujo/pen/mdOXdyB

if this help you check as correct or voteup!

Comment: Why the codepen? An [inline code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) should be enough right?

Comment: Ow, also, the codepen shows the vertical line, same problem as OP.

Comment: the link of codepen is a example of the change.

Comment: do you waint horizontal line too?

Comment: remove display: flex and change this hr property. Look in codepen now.

Answer (score 0):

Make it behave like a table is one way *(but needs a few wrapping divs)*:

```html
<div class="w">
  <span class="a">Des habitations pour tous</span>
  <div class="b"><hr></div>
  <button class="c">COLLECTIONS</button>
</div>
```

```css
.w {
  display: table;
}
.a, .b, .c {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.b {
  width: 100%;
}
```